# How to fill a select using Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel

I'm a beginner in laravel, I have a submit form add salary, table salary contains a foreign key to table function, in the form I want to fill select with function_id to choose the function of a salary, but it gives me error Undefined variable : functions.

**create.blade.php**

```
<select class="form-control" name="function_id">
    <option></option>
    @foreach($functions as $function)
        <option value="{{ $function->id }}">{{ $function->function}}</option>
    @endforeach
</select>
```

**salaryController.php**

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use App\Salary;
use App\Function;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class SalaryController extends Controller
{
    public function getFunctions(Request $request)
    {
        $functions = Function::get();

        return view("salary.create", compact("functions"));
    }
}
```

**web.php**

```
Route::get('/getFunctions','SalaryController@getFunctions');
```

**Function.php**

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Function extends Model
{
    //
}
```

Comment: Whats is your output of dd($fonctions);

Comment: Does it show you this error when you load the page or after you've submitted the form?

Comment: @TalhaF. thx for answer ,i want get fonctions

Comment: @Rwd load the page,

Comment: @SokMa In your controller I need the output of $fonctions, you can check the output by dd as dd($fonctions);

Comment: You get Undefined variable : functions or Undefined variable : fonctions ???

Comment: @TalhaF. $fonctions is undefined

Comment: @TalhaF. Undefined variable: fonctions

Comment: Please edit your controller like this and give me the output

        public function getFonctions(Request $request)
    {
        $fonctions = Fonction::get();

        dd($fonctions);
    }

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/207583/discussion-between-talha-f-and-sok-ma).

Comment: @TalhaF. Undefined variable: fonctions (View: D:\wamp\www\BTPl\resources\views\salarie\create.blade.php)

Comment: Have you shown all of the code in your `create.blade.php` file? If not, please may you edit your question and include all of the code for that file.

Answer (score 1):

I just the name of your variable is wrong in your controller :

```
class SalaryController extends Controller
{
    public function getFunctions(Request $request)
    {
        $functions = Function::get();

        // you put "fonctions"
        return view("salarie.create", compact("functions"));
    }
}
```

**EDIT**

You fix the variable name in your last edit ?